# How to share code between Python internals projects?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multi-project, code-sharing

Let's say I am building an event-driven architecture, with Python microservices. I have a `stream package` handling all interactions with the streaming platform. It is supposed to be used internally only, in the company.

```
stream
    __init__.py
    produce.py
    process.py
    security.py
```

What are my options for sharing this package between all my Python microservices?

Should I publish my `stream package` so my projects can install it?

Is there some kind of [Gradle](https://gradle.org/) for python including the Multi project feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [package your Python code to reusable packages](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/).

[Poetry is a popular modern tool](https://python-poetry.org/) to manage your Python package.

Poetry, and other Python package managers like pip, can directly install private packages from an internal file server or Git link.

Comment: Looks great! Poetry Repositories are an answer. Just need to configure additional package sources.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to publish your Python modules to install them with `pip`. See [Packaging Python projects](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects) from the Python documentation to understand how to create installable packages (Wheel, `.whl`) from your project and stop once you've got the `.whl` file (don't have to upload to the public package index). Then, you can put them either into your company-internal Python package index (e.g., artifactory) or into an object storage service or Git LFS, from where your other microservices can access and install the package during build with

```
pip install /path/to/your/stream-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl
```

Comment: Great too! but seems more laborious.

Comment: Yes, this is IT by foot. But it works with built-in tools.